# remove query string from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Can anyone help me to remove query string from URL using .htaccess

Current URL

```
xyz.com/blog-detail?slug=slugvalue
```

I want this type of url

```
xyz.com/blog-detail/slugvalue
```

Basically I want slug value in URL and remove parameter from URL

Here is my code:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
```

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifmodule>


# BEGIN Expire headers  
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>  
 #  # Turn on the module.
  ExpiresActive on
  # Set the default expiry times.
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

here is my all htaccess file code

```
# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

please check all above code of my file

please help me to solve my issue

Comment: use RewriteRule with mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: I have created  this code but i think it's not work with whole website

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug\=slugvalue$
RewriteRule ^blog\-detail$ http://example.com/blog-detail/slugvalue? [R=301,L]

Comment: here i want automatic detect slug value

Comment: @KunalVerma, Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please also mention sample URL which you are hitting in browser?

Comment: @KunalVerma, also in case you are hitting link `http://example.com/blog-detail?slug=slugvalue` then from which file in backend its getting served? Eg: blog.php OR index.php etc?

Comment: yes here is the url https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail?slug=test

I want this https://www.beyondmaids.com/blog-detail/test

please help me on this

Comment: @KunalVerma, sure, please answer to my previous comment, on by which file your url is being served?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 website build in Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following htaccess rules.
Please make sure to place these rules at the top of your htaccess file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Checking condition and getting matches in variables to be used while redirect in next rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?slug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to php file for frontend request:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  blog-detail.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: this code conduct a error of 500

Comment: @KunalVerma, do you have any other rules apart from these?

Comment: Yes i have here is my htaccess file please check and help me to solve this problem https : // we.tl/t-xErHcqk1RC

Comment: @KunalVerma, please don't post links, rather post complete htacess in your question itself and let me know then.

Comment: I have added all the code in question please check

Comment: can you please check

Comment: @KunalVerma, checked that, did you place these rules above your current rules? Also again from which php file it should be served?

Comment: blog-detail.php file

Comment: @KunalVerma, try my updated rules and make sure to keep these rules top of your file. Remove your tried rules which you done for this one, try and let me know how it goes. Make sure your htaccess and php file are in same directory(blog-detail.php and htacess should be in same folder).

Comment: Updated code is working correctly but now page css can't work means whole design messed up

Comment: @KunalVerma, You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Thanks alot sir you have solved my big problem

Comment: @KunalVerma, you have done it now, cheers and happy learning, keep posting Good)with your tried code and efforts) questions and answers on this nice forum, cheers.

Comment: Now I have face another issue now my this url https://www.beyondmaids.com/project?slug=Ipe-Deck-power-washing-in-Sands-Point-NY-Long-Island goes to 404

Comment: i think it's due to we mention particular page name

Comment: Can you help me here to solve this issue

Comment: @KunalVerma, request you to please open a new question with full details and I can check it there, normally its encouraged to open 1 question 1 thread please. Let me know once done.

Comment: I opened a new question can you please check